# Pythonic way of returning a value depending of results of multiple functions

Tags: python

I want to return a value depending on which among a set of functions returns true.

```
if a():
    return 'a'
elif b():
    return 'b'
else:
    return 'c'
```

is there a more pythonic way of doing so?

Comment: maybe a ternary expression?

Comment: `return 'a' if a() else ('b' if b() else 'c')`

Comment: yes, that works. Thanks.

Comment: Using a nested conditional expression *is definitely not more pythonic* than using `if...elif...else`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just a question of taste. but I would just call that shorter in term of lines, not necessarily more pythonic. if there are more than 2 conditions, ternary is just not the way to do it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I agree. But personally, I think nested conditional expressions are difficult to read, whereas an `if...elif..else` block is *extremely* readable.

Comment: Coal_ answer is perfect when there's a lot of conditions. There are only 2 in OP question, but this could be generalized. But I'm not losing any opportunity to promote ternary, as this can save you in functional programming.

Answer (score 4):

If you can put all of the functions into an iterable:

```
functions = [a, b]
for func in functions:
    if func():
        return func.__name__
return "c"
```

This makes more sense when supplied with lots of functions, as the only thing that changes is `functions` (and optionally a 'default' return value). If you want this as a function:

```
def return_truthy_function_name(*functions, default):
    """Iterate over `*functions` until a function returns a truthy value, then return its name.
    If none of the functions return a truthy value, return `default`.
    """
    for function in functions:
        if function():
            return function.__name__
    return default
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's more pythonic, but it's shorter using 2 nested ternary expressions:

```
return 'a' if a() else ('b' if b() else 'c')
```

if there are more than 2 conditions, nesting ternary expressions becomes ludicrious and the loop approach of [Coal_ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444009/pythonic-way-of-returning-a-value-depending-of-results-of-multiple-functions/47444040#47444040) (maybe using a list of `tuples` to associate the function call and the return value if there's no obvious relation between the 2) is better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a conditional expression:

```
return 'a' if a() else 'b' if b() else 'c'
```

Comment: You came a minute too late ;-)

Comment: This is almost the same as Jean-François Fabre&#39;s answer.

Comment: But this doesn't use parentheses, thus making it even shorter ;). Let's code golf this

Comment: I've put parentheses in for the sake of safety. I don't like juggling with knives.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {a: 'a() is true',
     b: 'b() is true',
     c: 'c() is true'}

for func, answer in d.items():
  if func():
    return answer
return 'nothing seems to be true'
```

Comment: again: make that an ordered dict, or you cannot predict the order of the evaluations. Those wouldn't be equivalent to OP case. Actually a list of tuples would be even better since you're not using random lookup dict feature.

Answer (score -1):

Actually a ***rather pythonic*** and generalizable way to do what you ask is probably

```
next((f for f in [a,b] if f()), c).__name__
```

Note that the callable `c` (defined on purpose) is used as default if the generator is empty.

Comment: So @Jean why did you change your mind ?